# PHP Query POST foreach only shows 77 of the 80 options from the form

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form that queries from a mysql database. This specific one outputs 79 lines. When I submit and then try to split with foreach() into an array it will max out at 77 lines. No matter which parts I make active and even adding new ones.

```
$counterVar=0;

foreach($_POST['count'] as $row=>$value) { 

    if(number_format(($_POST['partsprice'][$row] * $_POST['new_qty'][$row]), 2, '.', '') > '0.00'){
        //$row_data[] = "(DEFAULT, '".$count[$row]."', '".$rma[$row]."', '".$ln[$row]."', '0', '".$item_key[$row]."', '".$qty[$row]."', '".$part_n[$row]."', '".$desc[$row]."', '".number_format($part_price1[$row], 2, '.', '')."', '".number_format($roll_out1[$row], 2, '.', '')."', '".number_format(($part_price1[$row] * $qty[$row]), 2, '.', '')."', '".number_format(($roll_out1[$row] * $qty[$row]), 2, '.', '')."', '".$cost_type[$row]."', '".$stkrm[$row]."', '".$bin[$row]."','5')<BR>";
        $row_data[] = "(DEFAULT, '".$_POST['count'][$row]."', '".$_POST['rma'][$row]."', '".$_POST['linenum'][$row]."', '0', '".$_POST['item_key'][$row]."', '".$_POST['new_qty'][$row]."', '".$_POST['part_num'][$row]."', '".$_POST['part_desc'][$row]."', '".number_format($_POST['partsprice'][$row], 2, '.', '')."', '".number_format($_POST['rolloutprice'][$row], 2, '.', '')."', '".number_format(($_POST['partsprice'][$row] * $_POST['new_qty'][$row]), 2, '.', '')."', '".number_format(($_POST['rolloutprice'][$row] * $_POST['new_qty'][$row]), 2, '.', '')."', '".$_POST['cost_type'][$row]."', '".$_POST['stkrm'][$row]."', '".$_POST['bin'][$row]."','5')<BR>";
    }
    $counterVar++; 
}
```

Update code

```
$counterVar = 0;
$row_data   = [];

$aEach = isset($_POST['count']) ? (array)$_POST['count'] : []; 

foreach($aEach as $row => $value) {

     $fPartsPrice = isset($_POST['partsprice'][$row]) ? (float)$_POST['partsprice'][$row] : 0; 
     $fNewQnty    = isset($_POST['new_qty'][$row]) ? (float)$_POST['new_qty'][$row] : 0;



    if(floatval($fPartsPrice * $fNewQnty) > 0) {

        $row_data[] = "(DEFAULT, '".$_POST['count'][$row]."',
         '".$_POST['rma'][$row]."', '".$_POST['linenum'][$row]."', '0', 
         '".$_POST['item_key'][$row]."', '".$_POST['new_qty'][$row]."',
         '".$_POST['part_num'][$row]."', '".$_POST['part_desc'][$row]."',
         '".number_format($_POST['partsprice'][$row], 2, '.', '')."', 
         '".number_format($_POST['rolloutprice'][$row], 2, '.', '')."',
         '".number_format(($_POST['partsprice'][$row] * $_POST['new_qty'][$row]), 2, '.', '')."',
         '".number_format(($_POST['rolloutprice'][$row] * $_POST['new_qty'][$row]), 2, '.', '')."', 
         '".$_POST['cost_type'][$row]."', '".$_POST['stkrm'][$row]."', '".$_POST['bin'][$row]."','5')<BR>";
    }


$counterVar++; 

}

$values=implode(",",$row_data);
echo $values;
echo "<br>";
echo 'items: '.count($row_data).'<br />'; 
echo 'counter: '.$counterVar.'<br />'; `
```

Comment: What is the value on `$counterVar` after the foreach is completed?

Comment: The `if(){}` is probably failing for certain lines so you end up with less lines than you expect

Comment: @AdarshMohan `$counterVar` is probably the "correct" number of lines but it's useless because OP needs to put it inside the `if(){}` clause.

Comment: It's not usually a good idea to do comparisons on formatted numbers, do the comparison with the regular number.

Comment: Try adding an `else` block that adds the other lines to another array, then see what's in that second array.

Comment: Or just print something in the `else` block.

Comment: Or try without if statement.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what `$_POST['count']`exactly contains, but its not a good idea to compare a formatted number against a string. BTW, you *should* check and validate your input vars.

My suggestion to fix that is:

```
$counterVar = 0;
$row_data   = [];

$aEach = isset($_POST['count']) ? (array)$_POST['count'] : []; 

foreach($aEach as $row => $value) { 

    $fPartsPrice = isset($_POST['partsprice'][$row]) ? (float)$_POST['partsprice'][$row] : 0; 
    $fNewQnty    = isset($_POST['new_qty'][$row]) ? (float)$_POST['new_qty'][$row] : 0; 

if(floatval($fPartsPrice * $fNewQnty) > 0) {
        $row_data[] = /* YOUR STUFF*/;
    }

    $counterVar++; 
}
echo 'items: '.count($row_data).'<br />'; 
echo 'counter: '.$counterVar.'<br />';
```

Sry for the bad formatting.It seems the wysiwyg does'nt like me :-) 
=> Now, if a line is missing in your `$row_data`, the calculation `$fPartsPrice * $fNewQnty` gives you zero or less.

Comment: So I copied over your suggestion and get the exact same results. Stops at 77. I will attach a image of the bottom of the php form and then the results I get and the code I updated with yours.

Comment: Here is a link of the images from the query and the submisison <https://imgur.com/a/oLssrNe>. @JakobKronsteiner

Comment: Hm ok, would you please execute  var_dump($_POST['count']); to show whats in if possible? Maybe you wanna use http://phpfiddle.org/

Comment: I found that one of the queried responses could be set static and not need to be in the array to the results. I removed that and everything worked.